# Why no output is shown when a code is run in visual studio code

Tags: visual-studio-code, output

When I click "run code" in VS Code, nothing happens. No output is shown, not even error is displayed anywhere.

[image]

Comment: When you mean "click run code", do you mean you press the play button on the upper right corner? Or should I say, did you run the code using the "Code Runner" extension?

Answer (score 2):

It worked for me changing the name of the file to .html, then after switching back to a .js file it worked for me

Answer (score 1):

First, you have to save the file. It does not seem like that in the screenshot.

Comment: CTRL+S is a quick way to do this on Windows. CMD+S for Mac.